# Automated website interaction - Mechanzie - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize-ruby

I'm using the [Mechanize gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) to automate interaction with a website form.

The site i'm trying to interact with is http://www.tastekid.com/like/books

I'm trying to automatically submit a string to query in the form and return the suggested books in an array.

Following [the guide](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html), i've pretty printed the page layout to find the form name, but, I am just finding a form with no name, nill:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.tastekid.com/like/books')
pp page
```

**How do I enter a string, submit the form and return the results in the form of an array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answers feel a little cluttered to me, so let me try to make it simpler:

```
page = agent.get 'http://www.tastekid.com/like/books'
```

there's only one form, so:

```
form = page.form
form['q'] = 'twilight'
```

submit the form

```
page = form.submit
```

print the text from the a's

```
puts page.search('.books a').map &:text
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [guide](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html), you can get the form:

```
form = page.form
```

I didn't see a name on the form, and I actually got two forms back:  one on the page and one hidden.

I called

```
form.fields.first.methods.sort  #not the hidden form
```

and saw that I could call `value` on the form, so I set it as such:

```
form.fields.first.value = "Blood Meridian"
```

then I submitted and pretty printed:

```
page = agent.submit(form)
```

This should work for you!

Comment: Thank you! How do I grab the book titles out of the #<Mechanize::Page:0x007fe0be025c00> object?

Comment: When doing a pretty print, it looks like all the titles are under Mechanize::Page::Link, how do I select just the book titles so I can put them in an array?

Comment: You will want to read up on `Nokogiri` to figure out how to parse the contents of the search results page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`form_with`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-form_with) method to locate the form you want.  For example:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.tastekid.com/like/books')

the_form_you_want = page.form_with(:id => "searchFrm")  # form_with
the_form_you_want.q = 'No Country for Old Men'
page = agent.submit(the_form_you_want)
pp page
```

It looks like the book titles all have the same class attribute.  To extract the book titles, use the [`links_with`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-links_with) method and pass in the class as a locator:

```
arr = []

page.links_with(:class => "rsrc").each do |link|
  arr << link.text
end
```

But @aceofbassgreg is right.  You'll need to read up on the mechanize and nokogiri documentation...

Comment: Is this way more efficient than the other answer? How do I extract the book titles only and push them in an array? The pretty print gives me a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Cormac McCarthy for the win on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @aceofbassgreg: Indeed! :)